# OnAction Runtime Error "1004" on initial run

Tags: vba, excel

Background:  I have a workbook that logs Olympic lift weights/history.  The user is able to create new lifts by pressing a button (Add New Lift) which calls a macro "New_Lift" and "Create_Button".  This will create a new worksheet with lift name, create a new column on the main sheet with the lift's name, add a button (main sheet) called "Log History" (OnAction = new worksheet sub).

The new worksheet, columns, and button are created fine, but receive a runtime error "1004" when the macro is run for the first time after opening the workbook (works fine thereafter).  The error points to the '.OnAction' of the button.  Below is a screenshot of the main sheet and the "Create_Button" code.  Any help is greatly appreciated and please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

#### Workbook Screenshot

[image: Workbook Screenshot]

```
Sub Add_New_Lift()

'*****************************************************************************************************
' This macro creates a new columns that contains the lift name, "Current", "Goal", "% Goal" and formulas
'*****************************************************************************************************
Dim ecol As Integer
Dim erow As Integer
Dim NewLift As String
Dim Lift_Metcon As String
Dim SheetCodeName As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Ask user to provide the name of the lift through a message box
NewLift = InputBox("New Lift Name:", "Add New Lift")

If StrPtr(NewLift) = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    Do
    Lift_Metcon = InputBox("Is this a Lift (Weight), Metcon (Time), or AMRAP (Total Reps):" & _
                    vbCrLf & vbTab & "-   Lift" & _
                    vbCrLf & vbTab & "-   Metcon" & _
                    vbCrLf & vbTab & "-   AMRAP" _
                    , "Type of Measurement")
        
    If StrPtr(Lift_Metcon) = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf (Lift_Metcon = "Lift") Or (Lift_Metcon = "Metcon") Or (Lift_Metcon = "AMRAP") Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        MsgBox "You have not made a valid entry.  Please try again."
    End If
    Loop
End If

'Find first empty column to add the new lift and formatting as well as Column letters for use with formula
ecol = Worksheets("Main").Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Column
ColNo1 = ecol
ColLet1 = Split(Cells(, ColNo1).Address, "$")(1)
ColNo2 = ecol + 1
ColLet2 = Split(Cells(, ColNo2).Address, "$")(1)
ColNo3 = ecol + 2
ColLet3 = Split(Cells(, ColNo3).Address, "$")(1)


'Formatting
    Worksheets("Main").Activate
    Columns(ecol).Select
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlMedium
    Range(Cells(3, ecol), Cells(3, ecol + 2)).Merge
    Cells(3, ecol) = NewLift
    Cells(3, ecol).Font.Size = 16
    Cells(4, ecol) = "Current"
    Cells(4, ecol + 1) = "Goal"
    Cells(4, ecol + 2) = "% Goal"
    Range(Cells(3, ecol), Cells(4, ecol + 2)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Range(Cells(3, ecol), Cells(4, ecol + 2)).Font.Bold = True
    Range(Cells(3, ecol), Cells(4, ecol + 2)).ColumnWidth = 8
    Range(Cells(1, ecol), Cells(4, ecol + 2)).Interior.Color = RGB(166, 166, 166)
    Range(Cells(5, ecol + 2), Cells(100, ecol + 2)).Formula = "=IF(" & ColLet1 & "5<> """", " & ColLet1 & "5/" & ColLet2 & "5,"""" )"
    Range(Cells(5, ecol + 2), Cells(100, ecol + 2)).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    
    If Lift_Metcon = "Metcon" Then
        Range(Cells(5, ecol), Cells(100, ecol)).NumberFormat = "0.0"
    End If

'Create new worksheet with formatting
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = NewLift
Sheets(NewLift).Range("A2") = "Name"
Sheets(NewLift).Range("A1") = Lift_Metcon
Sheets(NewLift).Range("A1").Font.Color = RGB(166, 166, 166)
Sheets(NewLift).Range("A2:B2").Font.Bold = True
Sheets(NewLift).Range("A:A").ColumnWidth = 27
Sheets(NewLift).Range("A1:BZ2").Interior.Color = RGB(166, 166, 166)
Sheets(NewLift).Range("A1").RowHeight = 55
Sheets(NewLift).Range("B2") = "M/F"
Sheets(NewLift).Columns("C").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Sheets(NewLift).Range("A3").Select

For Each Cell In Range("A3:BZ100") ''change range accordingly
If Cell.Row Mod 2 = 1 Then ''highlights row 2,4,6 etc|= 0 highlights 1,3,5
    Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217) ''color to preference
Else
    Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone ''color to preference or remove
End If
Next Cell

SheetCodeName = ActiveSheet.CodeName

'Calls the CreateButton subroutine and passes the NewLift from user, last empty column and SheetCodeName (i.e. Sheet5)
Call CreateButton(NewLift, ecol, SheetCodeName)

Worksheets("Records").Activate
erow = Worksheets("Records").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
Cells(erow, 1) = NewLift

Worksheets("Main").Activate
Range("A5").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub



Sub CreateButton(NewLift As String, ecol As Integer, SheetCodeName As String)
Dim Code As String
Dim NewLiftSpace As String

NewLiftSpace = Replace(NewLift, " ", "_")
SheetCodeName = Worksheets(NewLift).CodeName

With ActiveSheet 'Main Sheet
    .Buttons.Add(Cells(2, ecol + 1).Left, Cells(2, ecol + 1).Top, 45, 45).Select
    Selection.Characters.Text = "Log" & vbCrLf & "History"
    Selection.OnAction = SheetCodeName & "." & NewLiftSpace & "_Button"
End With

'subroutine macro text
Code = "Public Sub " & NewLiftSpace & "_Button()" & vbCrLf
Code = Code & "Dim LiftSheet As String" & vbCrLf
Code = Code & "LiftSheet = " & """" & NewLift & """" & vbCrLf
Code = Code & "Call History.Log_History(LiftSheet)" & vbCrLf
Code = Code & "End Sub" & vbCrLf
Code = Code & "Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()" & vbCrLf
Code = Code & "UserForm1.Show" & vbCrLf
Code = Code & "Athlete_Chart(Athlete)" & vbCrLf
Code = Code & "End Sub"


'add macro at the end of the sheet module
With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ActiveSheet.CodeName).CodeModule
    .InsertLines .CountOfLines + 1, Code
End With

End Sub
```

**EDIT:** Code runs without errors if the VBA editor is open.

Comment: ........Cool code...........

Comment: I think it is a naming issue, because you are missing the ! after the worksheet:  Selection.OnAction = SheetCodeName & "!" & NewLiftSpace & "_Button"

Comment: I changed it to your suggestion (Selection.OnAction = SheetCodeName & "!" & NewLiftSpace & "_Button"), but no such luck.  Still receive the "1004" error on the initial run of opening the workbook, but continues to work fine afterward.

Comment: Have you tried switching the "code"-subroutine with the "with"-loop above it?

Comment: So I moved the "code" sub to be above the "with" (button) loop and no such luck.  Still "1004" error.

Comment: I can't replicate a 1004 error with the code that you posted.  Can you edit the question to include the calling code?

Comment: @Comintern, I have included the calling code.  This is the complete code when the user selects "Add New Lift" on the "Main" sheet.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

it's because after `Sheets.Add(...` the new sheet becomes the *Active* and once in `CreateButton()` the statement:

```
With ActiveSheet 'Main Sheet
```

is actually referencing the new added sheet and not "Main" one as you expected

Bottom line, avoid `Activate`/`ActiveXXX`/`Select`/`Selection` coding pattern as much as possible and use fully qualified range references as in the following refactoring of your code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Add_New_Lift()

    '*****************************************************************************************************
    ' This macro creates a new columns that contains the lift name, "Current", "Goal", "% Goal" and formulas
    '*****************************************************************************************************
    Dim ecol As Integer, ColNo1 As Integer, ColNo2 As Integer, ColNo3 As Integer
    Dim ColLet1 As String, ColLet2 As String, ColLet3 As String
    Dim erow As Integer
    Dim NewLift As String
    Dim Lift_Metcon As String
    Dim SheetCodeName As String
    Dim cell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    'Ask user to provide the name of the lift through a message box
    NewLift = InputBox("New Lift Name:", "Add New Lift")

    If StrPtr(NewLift) = 0 Or NewLift = "" Then Exit Sub
    Do
        Lift_Metcon = InputBox("Is this a Lift (Weight), Metcon (Time), or AMRAP (Total Reps):" & _
                        vbCrLf & vbTab & "-   Lift" & _
                        vbCrLf & vbTab & "-   Metcon" & _
                        vbCrLf & vbTab & "-   AMRAP" _
                        , "Type of Measurement")
        If StrPtr(Lift_Metcon) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Loop While Not ((Lift_Metcon = "Lift") Or (Lift_Metcon = "Metcon") Or (Lift_Metcon = "AMRAP"))

    'Find first empty column to add the new lift and formatting as well as Column letters for use with formula
    With Worksheets("Main") '<--| reference your "Main" sheet
        ecol = .Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Column
        ColNo1 = ecol
        ColLet1 = Split(.Cells(, ColNo1).Address, "$")(1)
        ColNo2 = ecol + 1
        ColLet2 = Split(.Cells(, ColNo2).Address, "$")(1)
        ColNo3 = ecol + 2
        ColLet3 = Split(.Cells(, ColNo3).Address, "$")(1)

        'Formatting
        With .Columns(ecol) '<--| reference referenced sheet 'ecol'th column
            .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlMedium
        End With
        .Range(.Cells(3, ecol), .Cells(3, ecol + 2)).Merge
        .Cells(3, ecol) = NewLift
        .Cells(3, ecol).Font.Size = 16
        .Cells(4, ecol) = "Current"
        .Cells(4, ecol + 1) = "Goal"
        .Cells(4, ecol + 2) = "% Goal"
        .Range(.Cells(3, ecol), .Cells(4, ecol + 2)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Range(.Cells(3, ecol), .Cells(4, ecol + 2)).Font.Bold = True
        .Range(.Cells(3, ecol), .Cells(4, ecol + 2)).ColumnWidth = 8
        .Range(.Cells(1, ecol), .Cells(4, ecol + 2)).Interior.Color = RGB(166, 166, 166)
        .Range(.Cells(5, ecol + 2), .Cells(100, ecol + 2)).Formula = "=IF(" & ColLet1 & "5<> """", " & ColLet1 & "5/" & ColLet2 & "5,"""" )"
        .Range(.Cells(5, ecol + 2), .Cells(100, ecol + 2)).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        If Lift_Metcon = "Metcon" Then .Range(.Cells(5, ecol), .Cells(100, ecol)).NumberFormat = "0.0"

        'Create new worksheet with formatting
        With Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)) '<--| this will make the new sheet the "Active" one
            .Name = NewLift
            .Range("A2") = "Name"
            .Range("A1") = Lift_Metcon
            .Range("A1").Font.Color = RGB(166, 166, 166)
            .Range("A2:B2").Font.Bold = True
            .Range("A:A").ColumnWidth = 27
            .Range("A1:BZ2").Interior.Color = RGB(166, 166, 166)
            .Range("A1").RowHeight = 55
            .Range("B2") = "M/F"
            .Columns("C").Select
            ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

            For Each cell In .Range("A3:BZ100") ''change range accordingly
                If cell.Row Mod 2 = 1 Then ''highlights row 2,4,6 etc|= 0 highlights 1,3,5
                    cell.Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217) ''color to preference
                Else
                    cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone ''color to preference or remove
                End If
            Next cell
            SheetCodeName = .CodeName

        End With
        .Activate '<--| jump back to referenced (i.e.: "Main") sheet and make it active again

        'Calls the CreateButton subroutine and passes the NewLift from user, last empty column and SheetCodeName (i.e. Sheet5)
        CreateButton NewLift, ecol, SheetCodeName

    End With
    Worksheets("Records").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = NewLift

errHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub



Sub CreateButton(NewLift As String, ecol As Integer, SheetCodeName As String)
    Dim Code As String
    Dim NewLiftSpace As String

    NewLiftSpace = Replace(NewLift, " ", "_")
    SheetCodeName = Worksheets(NewLift).CodeName

    With ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(Cells(2, ecol + 1).Left, Cells(2, ecol + 1).Top, 45, 45) '<--| reference a new button on active sheet
        .Characters.Text = "Log" & vbCrLf & "History"
        .OnAction = SheetCodeName & "." & NewLiftSpace & "_Button"
    End With

    'subroutine macro text
    Code = "Public Sub " & NewLiftSpace & "_Button()" & vbCrLf
    Code = Code & "Dim LiftSheet As String" & vbCrLf
    Code = Code & "LiftSheet = " & """" & NewLift & """" & vbCrLf
    Code = Code & "Call History.Log_History(LiftSheet)" & vbCrLf
    Code = Code & "End Sub" & vbCrLf
    Code = Code & "Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()" & vbCrLf
    Code = Code & "UserForm1.Show" & vbCrLf
    Code = Code & "Athlete_Chart(Athlete)" & vbCrLf
    Code = Code & "End Sub"

    'add macro at the end of the sheet module
    With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(SheetCodeName).CodeModule '<--| reference your new sheet 'CodeName'
        .InsertLines .CountOfLines + 1, Code
    End With

End Sub
```

where I deliberatley choose to leave that:

```
.Activate '<--| jump back to referenced (i.e.: "Main") sheet and make it active again
```

because I intended you needed to leave the user with "Main" sheet as the active one

so I also exploited it to leave `ActiveSheet` reference in CreateButton() to implicitly refer to "Main" sheet instead of changing Sub *signature* adding a new argument (a reference to "Main" sheet or its name) to use and reference "Main" sheet also

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I pasted your code in place of my code and I don't see the error, BUT... The "code" string isn't getting written to the new worksheet (SheetCodeName) nor does it appear that the "Log History" button is getting assigned an .OnAction.

What is odd to me though, is that as soon as I open the VBA editor and rerun the "Add New Lift", everything works fine.

Comment: I don't get you: are you done or do you still have issues?

Comment: I'm not receiving the Runtime "1004" error anymore, but the "code" string is not getting written to the new worksheet and the "Log History" button is not getting assigned an action.

Comment: After further inspection, the code works, but only if the VBA Editor is open.  It throws a Runtime "9" error where the code is written to the new worksheet (SheetCodeName) if the VBA Editor is not open.  I guess this might be from a memory issue.

Comment: Below is the code that writes the "code" string and throws the runtime "9" error, unless the VBA Editor is open.  I will do some code stepping this afternoon to see what I can find.  Thanks!.........

        With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(SheetCodeName).CodeModule '<--| reference your new sheet 'CodeName'
        .InsertLines .CountOfLines + 1, Code
    End With